# Connection String Visual Studio 2013 database -- unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=MAX-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=newSchool;Integrated Security=True
```

but whenever I write :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAX-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=newSchool;Integrated Security=True");
```

it gives me an error

> unrecognized escape sequence

under the `\` in `Max-PC\SQLEXPRESS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `MAX-PC\\SQLEXPRESS`.  Note the use of two backslashes, not one.  It's saying that it doesn't recognize the escape sequence `\S`

**See Also**
[Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

`\` is a speacial character to create [escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx). you can use `\\` or you can put `'@'` beginning of your connection string to ignore escape characters

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MAX-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=newSchool;Integrated Security=True");
```

Answer (score 3):

C# will understand the '\S' as an escape character. The correct would be double back-slash, or the use of @ before the opening ".

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAX-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=newSchool;Integrated Security=True");
```

or

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MAX-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=newSchool;Integrated Security=True");
```